# Is there a known issue when searching for decimals in a Data table via DataTableRequest?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I seem to have some strange behaviour when searching for a decimal through my Datatable. I have a column "Price" in my table which is populated with decimals. When I try to search my table it works fine with decimals like "1.2", "2.5", "1.1" etc however when I search for "0.9", "0.7" it doesn't seem to like the "0" at the front as it does not find any records. If I were to use ".9" or ".7" then records with "0.9" or "0.7" would be found.

I have debugged all the way through my code and the "0.9" is carried throughout so I'm not sure what is going wrong

Could anyone help?

[image: Data without search]
[image: Searching with 0.9]
[image: Searching with .9]
[image: Searching with 1.2]

Comment: What is your culture settings?  The culture may be using a comma instead of a period for the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is why I'm confused, if the culture settings were using a comma then wouldn't it cause other decimals to not work either like "1.2"?

Comment: well maybe you are getting One thousand - two hundred, and not one and two tenths.

Comment: It's stored as a 1.2 decimal though

Comment: It looks like you're searching for strings, not decimals.  Are you declaring ````Decimal d = 0.9M;```` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The value is stored as a decimal, however my search by function is searching for a string because it's a multi column search box so for example, if I searched for "0" it would check all columns for "0" and not just my decimal column. Do you think this is the cause then?